# Why does my backspace return a new text instead of updating the current text?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am trying my hand at a self teaching project by creating a calculator. I am having trouble getting my backspace to update the text in my textbox. My goal is to be able to **Backspace** using my backspace button and add a number afterward and having my result being exactly whats expected with any backspace i.e.

(1) string of 701
(2) ***Backspace used***
(3) ***Adding 4 to the string***
(4) return 704

What I am thinking is that when I click the button it is returning a new string and when I enter a new number, it is updating the old string. I have tried this code in the btnBck_Click function as well as what I am showing in my current code(the BackSpaceFunction(); is my attempt to tell the program to return the updated string).

```
    private void btnBck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackSpaceFunction();
    }

    private string BackSpaceFunction()
    {
        string textBoxText = textBox1.Text;
        textBoxText = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBoxText.Length - 1);
        if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBoxText);
            return textBox1.Text;
        }

        else if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "0";
            input = string.Empty;
            operand1 = string.Empty;
            operand2 = string.Empty;
        }
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
```

(Please understand my excessive explaining and use of examples is to make sure everyone can understand in case I myself missed the point. Thank you in advance)

Comment: Q: It sounds like you're writing a C#/WinForms app, correct? Q: What's wrong with the normal "backspace" behavior?   What are you trying to do that isn't happening by default?  Also, C# strings are "immutable": `String objects are immutable: they cannot be changed after they have been created. All of the String methods and C# operators that appear to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings

Comment: That's correct. By normal "backspace" behavior do you mean something that I can call? What is currently happening is entering a text(12345) then backspace(1234) then adding an 8 but its returning (123458) instead of (12348)

Comment: If 1) you have a [Winforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio) app with a [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox), 2) and you type `12345`, `<backspace>` then `8`, then 3) you should see `12348` in the text box, *AND* 4) textBox1.Text should *ALSO* show `12348`.  Q: Is that not what's happening?

Comment: You are spot on. It should show 12348 but instead it shows 123458 and I am not sure why.

Comment: If you use a textbox ... and you type in the text box ... and you're not doing something ELSE that you're not telling us about ... then you should get "12348".  If you're "caching"  textBox1.Text in a separate string variable, or if you're processing individual keystrokes programmatically ...then DON'T.  Just let TextBox do it's job unimpeded ... and it should make you Happy :)

Comment: Instead of the useless tags "visual-studio" (which is mean for question regarding the VS IDE itself) and "project" (where I see no relation at all to your question), you should better tag your question "winforms" (to differentiate it from other UI frameworks like WPF, ASP.NET, Xamarin, ...) and maybe "textbox".

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble getting my backspace to update the text in my textbox

The `TextBox` control supports use of the backspace key directly. As long as the `TextBox` has the input focus, pressing the backspace key will delete the character just before the current insertion point.

Your code example is incomplete, but it looks like you have a separate `Button` object that is intended to provide similar functionality. You aren't taking into account the insertion point for the `TextBox`, so presumably you just always want to remove the last character. If that's the case, your method is far more complicated than it needs to be. You can just use [`string.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to remove the last character:

```cs
private string BackSpaceFunction()
{
    if (textBox1.Length > 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
    }

    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "0";
        input = string.Empty;
        operand1 = string.Empty;
        operand2 = string.Empty;
    }

    return textBox1.Text;
}
```

(You never actually use the return value, so it's not clear why the method has a return value. But I left that in because it's not inherently a problem.)

Comment: Thank  you for the time to reply and help out. The example you provided gave me the same issue I was having before. I am actually about to post my solution while I was messing around trying to fix it on my own.

Answer (score -1):

So to answer my own question, I took the time to try and figure it out for myself. I ended up succeeding and found that this code worked (look at the "if" portion of my if statement).

```
    private void btnBck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BackSpaceFunction();

    }

    private string BackSpaceFunction()
    {
        //textBoxText = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBoxText.Length - 1);
        if (textBox1.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            string textBoxText = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
            string updatedText = textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.Text, textBoxText);
            textBox1.Text = updatedText;
            input = string.Format(textBox1.Text, updatedText);
            operand1 = string.Format(textBox1.Text, updatedText);
            operand1 = string.Format(textBox1.Text, updatedText);
        }

        else if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "0";
            input = string.Empty;
            operand1 = string.Empty;
            operand2 = string.Empty;
        }
        return textBox1.Text;

    }'''
```

I'm not exactly sure why I had to use Format for **input**, **operand1**, and **operand2** but it ended up doing exactly what I needed. If there are any explanations as to why this worked I will gladly accept the learning opportunity. :)

Comment: Please, for our sanity, change `textBox1.Text.Replace(textBox1.text, textBoxText)` to `textBox1.Text = textBoxText`... that whole `Replace(...)` call is obfuscation at best and pointless at worst.